# Sqlite for client server program

Tags: qt, sqlite, client-server

I am writing a simple client server program in QT and now i want every message that client send to server save in "SQLite" in server side.
How can i do it?
Could you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried? SO isn't a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know the basics of socket programming.

To write client server program using Qt you can follow this article, http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpServer_Client_Server.php. This article also contains nice examples of client-server multithreaded programs using Qt. For maximum efficiency you must write multithreaded server program.

Once the message is received by server thread, you have to use SQLite API's to save that message in SQLite server. There are many articles available on internet about SQLite programming.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your complete and useful answer,